# Prevent "direct access" to menu items but keep them accessible when embedded in articles

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I've been building a Joomla website for a couple of weeks now and having started with virtually zero Joomla and PHP knowledge I have to say I've been kind of fumbling my way through all of this. Anyway, I'm having a small "problem" and hope you guys can help me sort it out:

I'm using [Plugin Include Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/8741) to embed content inside articles. Naturally, this content is associated with menu items. The thing is, I want these menu items to be accessible only through the articles in which they are embedded. This means that I want to somehow restrict direct access to the menu items, but still allowing users to see their content inside the articles.

For the sake of comprehension I'll try to be more graphic:

I have a Category Blog associated with menu item **A**.
By means of the plugin I mentioned above, I have **A** embedded inside article **B**. So far so good! When **B** is displayed, the category blog in **A** is also shown as a part of it. But I don't want users to be able to type **B**'s url into the browser and access it directly, because it's detrimental to my site's structure and navigation. Obviously, unpublishing the menu item wouldn't help at all because it would cease to be visible inside the article.

My apologies if I didn't make myself clear. Any hints or tips?

Comment: Are you having issue that the menu item is viewed as part of a menu displayed on the site or just that someone could type in the url of the menu item and it would display?

Comment: No, no problems at all, it's just that, as you say, there's a possibility that someone could type in the url of the menu item and access it directly. But I guess that there's no cure for that haha.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far as not being able to directly access the menu items for item A, just publish the menu item in a new menu that is not added to any module position. This way there are no direct links that the user can access through the front end.

As far as a user TYPING in the url for item A, you are out of luck. There is no way to prevent that. Once you have created the menu item, there is a URL which necessarily must be accessible. Using the hidden menu trick, the user would have to know that the URL exists to be able to get there, but it will be there if they know it. The way you are putting the site together the user shouldn't be to see the url so they will likely never type it in, but it would be possible.

Comment: Yep, I've used the hidden menu trick. What bothers me is that once the site is published and Google crawlers reach it, those links will eventually be visible to anyone who runs a search (am I right?). Anyway, it is not a life or death matter, just wanna keep things neat and tidy. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yep, @Brent Friar's answer gets you as far as you can without some custom code - or at least, I'm not aware of such a plugin that will do exactly as you wish. What I would say however is that, this is achievable by way of creating a content/system plugin that renders a hidden form in which a JToken is generated that is authenticated afterRoute in the requested page. Well, thats the general gist of it at least. I mean, you could make this plugin as simple or as complicated as you wished; include {placeHolders}, include/exclude cats, articles etc.

Comment: Google would only pick up links actually on your site. Since the plugin should handle all the linking server side, you shouldn't have to worry too much. The only hack I can think would be setting the access level on the hidden menu item to "special". If the plugin doesn't check the access level (I have no idea if it does or not) then it may still include it in the page while the menu item would be inaccessible through the menu item without being logged in as an admin.